# Highlighted color not cover all the table cell in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c

As the screenshot below, the highlighted color(blue) is not covered all the are of the cell, how can I make the highlighted color(blue) cover all the cell?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your subviews are covering the highlighting.  You can try setting the highlighted color of all subviews in the cell to the same color.  If its a `UIImageView` you would need to set the `highlightedImage` property to an image with a blue background, etc..